# Execute statement in pentaho cde sql over sqlJndi

Tags: pentaho-cde

I need to run a sql script that includes drop & create table as select & create index & select. Because this is a direct query (without ETL) to DB and you need to create a temporary table by performance. The problem is that CDE does not allow the ';' between sentences.

The solution I proposed is a button to execute each 'part', but I'm looking for something 'elegant' and automatic. I understand that with parameters it could be done, but I would need an example to achieve.